# How can i boot clonezilla backup?

Tags: backup, clonezilla

I just created a backup using clonezilla to an usb  stick. Now I would like to boot from this usb stick, but I'm getting a missing operating system error. How can I boot from the usb?

Comment: You need to install GRUB.

Comment: And how can I do that

Comment: Someone will help pretty soon. I've posted your question in chat since I don't know enough about Grub to properly answer your question with distributed ease. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Clonezilla Live.

> Clonezilla Live is a small bootable GNU/Linux distribution for x86/amd64 (x86-64) based computers. 
>   To install Clonezilla live, the basic steps are to download pre-build
>   Clonezilla Live then put it in a boot media (CD, USB flash drive or
>   USB hard drive). Two types of files are available, iso and zip. The
>   former one is for CD, the latter is for USB flash drive. Besides, you
>   can put Clonezilla live on hard drive or PXE server, too.
>   <sup>1</sup>

[Read on](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php)</sup>

Note: Once you create the CD/USB, make sure that your backup fits on the newly created bootable USB.

Comment: I already made the backup to a USB stick, but I would like to boot from the USB stick where the backed files are.

Comment: You have to make that USB bootable, the copy the backup back on it.

Comment: How can I make it bootable?

Comment: By using clonezilla live.  Click on the Read on in the answer for details.